# Canvas Multipliers Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to add a multiplier to the following code to produce a higher quality image when I save both sides of my canvas with this but am not having any luck (I am using fabricjs 1.7.22):

```
 // Save Canvases as Images
  $("#save").click(save);

  function download(url, name) {
    $("<a>")
      .attr({
        href: url,
        download: name
      })[0]
      .click();
  }

  function save() {
    mainCanvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
    var c = document.getElementById('canvas1');
    var dataURL = c.toDataURL();
    var name = 'back';
    download(dataURL({
      multiplier: 2
    }), name + ".png");
    var c = document.getElementById('canvas2');
    var dataURL = c.toDataURL();
    var name = 'front';
    download(dataURL({
      multiplier: 2
    }), name + ".png");
  }
```

It works with this similar code, but I'm missing something. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Save
function download(url, name) {
  // make the link. set the href and download. emulate dom click
  $('<a>').attr({
    href: url,
    download: name
  })[0].click();
}

function downloadFabric(canvas, name) {
  //  convert the canvas to a data url and download it.
  download(activeCanvas.toDataURL({
    multiplier: 2
  }), name + '.png');
}
```

I also tried adding the multiplier to `var dataURL = c.toDataURL` vars without luck.

---

Here is an example of my initialization:

```
var mainCanvas, canvas1, canvas2, view = false;

$(function () {
  $viewText = document.querySelector("#viewText");
  canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1', {
    preserveObjectStacking: true,
    lockUniScaling: true,
    centeredScaling: true
  });
  canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas2', {
    preserveObjectStacking: true,
    lockUniScaling: true,
    centeredScaling: true
  });
  canvas1.setHeight(412);
  canvas1.setWidth(637);
  canvas2.setHeight(412);
  canvas2.setWidth(637);
  changeView(1);

  // Center Line
  var line = new fabric.Line([canvas1.width / 2, 0, canvas1.width / 2, canvas1.height], {
    strokeWidth: 0.1,
    stroke: 'black',
    selectable: false,
  });
  canvas1.add(line);
  canvas2.add(line);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function save() {
  mainCanvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
  //canvas1 fabric canvas insance
  var dataURL = canvas1.toDataURL({
    multiplier: 2
  });
  var name = 'back';
  download(dataURL, name + ".png");
  //canvas2 fabric canvas insance
  var dataURL = canvas2.toDataURL({
    multiplier: 2
  });
  var name = 'front';
  download(dataURL, name + ".png");
}
```

You need to pass multiplier property to `toDataURL()`.

Comment: Oddly, this seems to be increasing the size of the image, but unlike my "working code" it's not nearly as clear. I'm not sure why this is, I'll do some further investigating. Do you know why the downloaded .png might be blurry? Thanks.

Comment: @codeforever `var c = document.getElementById('canvas1');` is it `canvas1` a fabricjs canvas?

Comment: Yes, it is a fabricjs canvas

Comment: @codeforever use the variable containing instance of fabricjs canvas.

Comment: I added my fabricjs initialization to my question (at the bottom). I think it'd still be `canvas1` and `canvas2`, right? Because we're saving both as individual images?

Comment: Okay, I will dig into this more and will post a bounty if I can't figure out what's going on